# package for geocoding (street location!) and next calculation of distance

Tags: google-maps, r, geocoding, distance

EDIT: And package for **not** geographical distance between two lan-long points, but distance **by car, or foot** (like this http://code.google.com/intl/sk/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) Travel mode - driving, walking. No map, just distance. Thanks for any idea.

---

Hello. I search package in R, what gives me longtitude and latitude for data frame with 10000 locations like this "STREET, town, Europe".

And then package, what gives me distance per haversine formula for those locations. But mainly package for lat-long.. Distance should be easy.

I searched a lot but found nothing useful for me. Thanks for help! I hope that R knows it :)

Comment: Oh we SO need an R interface to this API: http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/

Comment: Finally R didn´t disappoint ;)

Comment: MapQuest have a route-finding and driving/walking distance API: http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/ based on OSM data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `dismo` has address level `geocode()`, though installation can be difficult on some platforms.

Package `sp` has WGS84 ellipsoidal distance in `spDistsN1()`.

Comment: The `dismo` package is perfect for retrieving latitude and longitude for street addresses, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Getting street locations is going to need google's help or similar. Or possibly OpenStreetMap, but I'm not sure what the API is:

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/

For just cities, search the geonames database for populated places using my geonames package:

```
>library(geonames)

> GNsearch(q="Toronto",fcode="PPLA")
  countryName adminCode1           fclName countryCode      lng
1      Canada         08 city, village,...          CA -79.4163
                                      fcodeName toponymName fcl    name fcode
1 seat of a first-order administrative division     Toronto   P Toronto  PPLA
  geonameId      lat adminName1 population
1   6167865 43.70011    Ontario    4612191
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use function 'mapdist' in 'ggmap' package

Answer (score 1):

See package 'geosphere' for distances between lon/lat points.

'gdistance' does things like cost-distance (on grids).

For distances along roads etc perhaps you can use igraph

Answer (score 0):

You could try looping through your addresse using [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2007-May/002051.html) method.

Or leave R and take advantege of Python's [geopy](http://code.google.com/p/geopy/).

Comment: Thanks for geopy. It would be my second choice.